# Finding identical numbers in large files python

Tags: python, loops, parsing, large-data

I have two data files in python, each containing two-column data as below:

```
3023084 5764
9152549 5812
18461998 5808
45553152 5808
74141469 5753
106932238 5830
112230478 5795
135207137 5800
148813978 5802
154818883 5798
```

There are about 10M entries in each file (~400Mb).

I have to sort through each file and check if any number in the first column of one file matches any number in the first column in another file.

The code I currently have converted the files to lists:

```
ch1 = []
with open('ch1.txt', 'r+') as file: 
    for line in file: 
        if ':' not in line:
            line = line.split() 
            ch1.append([line[0], line[1]])

ch2 = []
with open('ch2.txt', 'r+') as file: 
    for line in file: 
        if ':' not in line:
            line = line.split() 
            ch2.append([line[0], line[1]])
```

I then iterate through both of the lists looking for a match. When a match is found I with to add the sum of the right hand columns to a new list 'coin'

```
coin = []
for item1 in ch1: 
    for item2 in ch2: 
        if item1[0] == item2[0]:
            coin.append(int(item1[1]) + int(item2[1]))
```

The issue is this is taking a very long time and or crashing. Is there a more efficient way of running with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *lots* of ways to improve this; for example:

- Since you only scan through the contents of `ch1.txt` once, you don't need to read it into a list, and should thus take up less memory, but probably won't speed things up all that much.
- If you sort each of your lists, you can check for matches *much* more efficiently.  Something like:

```
    i1, i2 = 0, 0
    while i1 < len(ch1) and i2 < len(ch2):
        if ch1[i1][0] == ch2[i2][0]:
            # Do what you do for matches
            ...
            # Advance both indices
            i1 += 1
            i2 += 1
        elif ch1[i1][0] < ch2[i2][0]:
            # Advance index of the smaller value
            i1 += 1
        else: # ch1[i1][0] > ch2[i2][0]
            i2 += 1
```

If the data in the files are already sorted, you can combine *both* ideas: instead of advancing an index, you simply read in the next line of the corresponding file.  This should improve efficiency in time *and* space.

Comment: The data are sorted in ascending order already. Could you suggest how to check matches more efficiently? I have tried @R.Marolahy 's solution but this crashes due to memory.

Answer (score 0):

Few ideas to improve this:

- store your data in dictionaries in such a way your first column is the key and the second column is the value of a dictionary for later use,
- a match is if a key is in the intersection of the keys of the two dictionaries

Code example:

```
# store your data in dicts as following
ch1_dict[line[0]] = line[1]
ch2_dict[line[0]] = line[1]

#this is what you want to achieve
coin = [int(ch1_dict[key]) + int(ch2_dict[key]) for key in ch1_dict.keys() & ch2_dict.keys()]
```

Comment: How does this improve efficiency, except in the length of the code?